# How do I calculate computational complexity of automatic differentiation?

Tags: complexity-theory, pytorch, automatic-differentiation, autograd

I'm using autogrid implemented in Pytorch to train a Neural Network and I need to calculate the computational complexity of the whole algorithm. Where do I find a complete calculation of computational complexity of the autograd? I've searched in the Pytorch documentation but I'm not finding any answer.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

try this https://github.com/Lyken17/pytorch-OpCounter. It calculates macs of nn(similar to complexity).
You could see some guide on the hub, use profile to measure the FLOPs of models in pytorch.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29853970)

Answer (score -1):

It depends on how you calculate complexity in this case. Each `forward` operation is paired with it's respective `backward` operation (returning derivative with respect to network's last node, usually cost function).

If you treat each operation as one unit, than forward and backward would be two units, essentially not changing anything in complexity, otherwise it depends on type of neural network and operations inside it.